# Create rectangle from UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I was wondering if its possible to create a rectangle from the image below to eliminate the weird corners:

[image: Rectangle]

Input Image:

```
<UIImage>, {1334, 955}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
int croppingNumber = 50;

CGRect croprect = CGRectMake(croppingNumber, imageToCrop.size.height - croppingNumber, imageToCrop.size.width - croppingNumber, imageToCrop.size.height - croppingNumber);

// Draw new image in current graphics context
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], croprect);

// Create new cropped UIImage
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

NSLog(@"cropped is: %@",croppedImage);

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Result from code above:

```
cropped is: <UIImage:>, {1338, 50}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow for enough to space to cover the right & bottom, so multiply your croppingNumber by 2. Otherwise, the 50 point shift to the right / down will just push your square into the bottom right most corner.

```
// Create rectangle from middle of current image
CGFloat croppingNumber = 50.0;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(croppingNumber, croppingNumber, imageToCrop.size.width - (croppingNumber * 2), imageToCrop.size.height - (croppingNumber * 2));

// Draw new image in current graphics context
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToCrop.CGImage, cropRect);

// Create new cropped UIImage
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

NSLog(@"cropped is: %@",croppedImage);

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

For anyone looking at this in the future, I am including the below image which shows the coordinates after the new rect is applied. This should help visualize what is going on.

[image]

Comment: No problem. I added the image as well to help visualize the end result.